# CQL Cassandra - How to use SELECT result in INSERT OR UPDATE

Tags: cassandra, cql

I'm really a beginner in Cassandra stuff.
I need to use some SELECT result in my INSERT.
Something like this:

```sql
insert into  data_tbl
  (value_type, time, value, key_id) 
values
  (
   'test1', 
   now(), 
   'my first value',
   (select key_id from keys where key='123') 
  );
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Try it and see? Have you tried it? Any errors?

Comment: No, it isn't possible

Answer (score 6):

As far as I know, you would need to do this programmatically in your application.  First do the select on the keys table, then as you read each row from the result set in a loop, do an insert into your data_tbl.

Comment: yes, this is probably the only way, except for the cql copy to file and from file. what a bummer...

Answer (score 3):

Nested query is an RDBMS concept not NoSQL. You cannot do it via CQL. If you need, you have to write your application in that way.